# Valums Uploader Using PHP with IE-9

Tags: javascript

I am using valums great uploader script. It works everywhere I tested except for IE9, where the spinner hangs forever and never stops. I've googled extensively and have found answers ranging from an updated JS file to simply adding the content type text/html to the PHP file, but nothing has worked.

Does anyone know what can be done?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try swfupload? Valums Uploader hasn't been updated in 2-3 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG - I fixed it!! Heres the answer:

In the qqUploadedFileXhr.php, there is a save($path) function. In it, there is another function called getName(). Replace it with the following:

```
function getName() {
if (isset($_GET['qqfile'])) {
    return $_GET['qqfile'];
} elseif (isset($_FILES['qqfile'])) {
    return $_FILES['qqfile']['name'];
}
}
```

IE9 uses $_FILES when uploading, not $_GET, so we need to check for that. So if $_FILES is set, we return the name of the file. Simple, works. Took me forever to figure out, so hopefully this helps you!